# Python Turtle installation Issue

Tags: python, python-turtle

```
 pip install turtle
Collecting turtle
  Using cached turtle-0.0.2.tar.gz (11 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [7 lines of output]
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-2pzr_rrh\turtle_eb2e3b23e85541d184dec515fb2d4ac2\setup.py", line 40
          except ValueError, ve:
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
      SyntaxError: multiple exception types must be parenthesized
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Need Solution to solve this

Comment: Isn't turtle built into cpython? If you open your python interpreter and type `import turtle`, what error message do you get?

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to install [this package](https://pypi.org/project/turtle/) from PyPI, which hasn't been updated since 2009. It probably doesn't work with the latest version of Python.

You're probably looking for [the turtle package that's built into Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/turtle.html).

If that's the case, you don't need to install anything. Just import `turtle` and start using it in a script:

```py
import turtle

turtle.begin_fill()
turtle.forward(200)
...
```